# Excel VBA - Need to loop through delete entire 3 rows above row where cell value <> 0

Tags: vba, excel

Okay, so I have an excel sheet that is formatted poorly for my purposes that I pull daily. The data is listed in the following format by default(as viewed on an excel sheet):

```
x1,y1,z1,i1
  ,  ,z2,i2
  ,  ,z3,i3
****Blank row****
****Blank row****
****Blank row****
x2,y2,z4,i4,
  ,  ,z5,i5,
  ,  ,z6,i6,

^above would represent the last row for demontration purposes, but the real
sheet extends up 1000s of rows
```

In order to get the data in a friendlier format, I need a loop that will start from the last row (erow) all the way up through row 3 (where the data begins). When it finds a row in column 2 that is <> to " ", I want it to delete the entire 3 rows above that cell, so the end goal is to have data formatted as such (as viewed on an excel sheet):

```
x1,y1,z1,i1
  ,  ,z2,i2
  ,  ,z3,i3
x2,y2,z4,i4
  ,  ,z5,i5
  ,  ,z6,i6
```

Below is what I have so far. Naturally, it doesn't work at all, otherwise I wouldn't be here. It is deleting all of my data up to row 3, and I can't figure out why. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
Sub test()

Dim currentSht As Worksheet
Dim erow
Dim i As Integer

Set currentSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
erow = currentSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For i = erow To 3 Step -3
If currentSht.Cells(i, 1).Value <> " " Then
    currentSht.Range(Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1), Cells(i, 1).Offset(-3)).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you keep testing the same row and deleting the 3 rows above.

Lets say `i` is 30 and it resolves to true, as in there is data in column 2.  We delete the three rows above it making the current row, row 27, then `i` iterates -3 and `i` is 27 and it test the same data and it resolve true again for the same data.

so we need to force `i` to change with the row number:

```
Sub test()

Dim currentSht As Worksheet
Dim erow
Dim i As Integer

Set currentSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
erow = currentSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For i = erow To 3 Step -1
If Trim(currentSht.Cells(i, 1).Value) <> "" Then
    currentSht.Range(Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1), Cells(i, 1).Offset(-3)).EntireRow.Delete
    i = i - 3
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. It did however only delete a portion of my data as my bottom row went from being at row 567 down to 519. Quickly scanning through the data, it looks like it worked in some areas, but not the vast majority of instances of 3 blank rows.

Comment: Is the `step -3` by chance causing it to hop over cells that contain data?

Comment: Are your groups always in threes like the example?

Comment: You can always try `step -1` instead. @AndyG

Comment: They're not, sorry I should have been more clear. The groups are completely variable.

Comment: Then you need to step -1 not -3.

Comment: @AndyG See edit I also made the check a little more robust.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you for all your help...I have never seen the Trim() function before. What is the purpose of it?

Comment: It removes any spaces before and after text.  so if there is a space or spaces in the column it removes them to an empty string for which we can test.  I have found that sometimes data when imported imports with spaces.  The way you had it with `" "` would look for a single space.  Most likely you do not have that in your data and would have emptied the whole thing again.

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the `IF`:

```
Sub test()

    Dim currentSht As Worksheet
    Dim erow
    Dim i As Integer

    Set currentSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    erow = currentSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = erow To 3 Step -3
        If currentSht.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
            currentSht.Range(Cells(i, 1).Offset(-1), Cells(i, 1).Offset(-3)).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```